# Google スプレッドシートへのデータフレーム追加時にエラー: type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.ListValue

Tags: python, python3, google-spreadsheet

クロールして取得したデータ（1行分）をスプレッドシートの最下行に反映したいのですが、下記エラーが表示されうまく反映されません。
解決方法はありますでしょうか。

**コード**

```
JSON_KEYFILE = 'APIのJSONファイル'
SPREADSHEET = 'TEST'
WORKSHEET = 'Sheet1'

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

#認証情報設定
serviceAccountCredentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(JSON_KEYFILE, scope)
gspreadClient = gspread.authorize(serviceAccountCredentials)
worksheet = gspreadClient.open(SPREADSHEET).worksheet(WORKSHEET)

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', encoding="shift_jis")
ls = df.loc[0:0]

ls = ls.to_json()

spread = client.open(SPREADSHEET) 
sheet = spread.worksheet(WORKSHEET)
worksheet.append_row(ls)
```

**エラーコード**

`worksheet.append_row(ls)` の部分でAPIエラーが発生してしまいます。

```
gspread.exceptions.APIError: {'code': 400, 'message': 'Invalid value at \'data.values[0]\' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.ListValue), "{"\\u58f2\\u4e0a\\u65e5":{"0":"2021\\/06\\/14"},"\\u30a4\\u30f3\\u30d7\\u30ec\\u30c3\\u30b7\\u30e7\\u30f3(I)":{"0":19},"\\u30af\\u30ea\\u30c3\\u30af(C)":{"0":36},"\\u30aa\\u30fc\\u30c0\\u30fc\\u767a\\u751f\\u4ef6\\u6570":{"0":0},"\\u30aa\\u30fc\\u30c0\\u30fc\\u767a\\u751f\\u500b\\u6570":{"0":0},"\\u30aa\\u30fc\\u30c0\\u30fc\\u30ad\\u30e3\\u30f3\\u30bb\\u30eb\\u500b\\u6570":{"0":0},"\\u30aa\\u30fc\\u30c0\\u30fc\\u58f2\\u4e0a\\u984d":{"0":0},"\\u30ad\\u30e3\\u30f3\\u30bb\\u30eb\\u76f8\\u5f53\\u984d":{"0":0},"\\u5831\\u916c\\u5bfe\\u8c61\\u7d14\\u58f2\\u4e0a\\u984d":{"0":0},"\\u5831\\u916c\\u5bfe\\u8c61\\u30af\\u30ea\\u30c3\\u30af\\u6570":{"0":0},"\\u5831\\u916c\\u5bfe\\u8c61\\u30ea\\u30fc\\u30c9(\\u63d0\\u643a\\u8ab2\\u91d1)\\u6570":{"0":0},"\\u6210\\u679c\\u5831\\u916c\\u984d":{"0":0},"\\u78ba\\u5b9a\\u60c5\\u5831":{"0":"\\u78ba\\u5b9a"}}"', 'status': 'INVALID_ARGUMENT', 'details': [{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest', 'fieldViolations': [{'field': 'data.values[0]', 'description': 'Invalid value at \'data.values[0]\' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.ListValue), "{"\\u58f2\\u4e0a\\u65e5":{"0":"2021\\/06\\/14"},"\\u30a4\\u30f3\\u30d7\\u30ec\\u30c3\\u30b7\\u30e7\\u30f3(I)":{"0":19},"\\u30af\\u30ea\\u30c3\\u30af(C)":{"0":36},"\\u30aa\\u30fc\\u30c0\\u30fc\\u767a\\u751f\\u4ef6\\u6570":{"0":0},"\\u30aa\\u30fc\\u30c0\\u30fc\\u767a\\u751f\\u500b\\u6570":{"0":0},"\\u30aa\\u30fc\\u30c0\\u30fc\\u30ad\\u30e3\\u30f3\\u30bb\\u30eb\\u500b\\u6570":{"0":0},"\\u30aa\\u30fc\\u30c0\\u30fc\\u58f2\\u4e0a\\u984d":{"0":0},"\\u30ad\\u30e3\\u30f3\\u30bb\\u30eb\\u76f8\\u5f53\\u984d":{"0":0},"\\u5831\\u916c\\u5bfe\\u8c61\\u7d14\\u58f2\\u4e0a\\u984d":{"0":0},"\\u5831\\u916c\\u5bfe\\u8c61\\u30af\\u30ea\\u30c3\\u30af\\u6570":{"0":0},"\\u5831\\u916c\\u5bfe\\u8c61\\u30ea\\u30fc\\u30c9(\\u63d0\\u643a\\u8ab2\\u91d1)\\u6570":{"0":0},"\\u6210\\u679c\\u5831\\u916c\\u984d":{"0":0},"\\u78ba\\u5b9a\\u60c5\\u5831":{"0":"\\u78ba\\u5b9a"}}"'}]}]}
```

Comment: エラーメッセージに `type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.ListValue` と表示されていますので、`append_row()` には JSON 形式ではなくリストを渡すのではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

[metropolis氏のコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/77615/%e3%82%b9%e3%83%97%e3%83%ac%e3%83%83%e3%83%89%e3%82%b7%e3%83%bc%e3%83%88%e3%81%b8%e3%81%ae%e3%83%87%e3%83%bc%e3%82%bf%e3%83%95%e3%83%ac%e3%83%bc%e3%83%a0%e3%81%ae%e8%bf%bd%e5%8a%a0#comment87737_77615)でもあるように、Sheets APIを使用して値をSpreadsheetへ挿入する場合は、セルに入るデータ部分はリストである必要があります。そこで、次のような修正はいかがでしょうか。

### Pattern 1:

このパターンでは、dataframeはリストに変換されて`values_update`メソッドを使ってセルへ挿入します。

#### From:

```py
ls = df.loc[0:0]
ls = ls.to_json()

spread = client.open(SPREADSHEET) 
sheet = spread.worksheet(WORKSHEET)
worksheet.append_row(ls)
```

#### To:

```py
ls = df.loc[0:0]

values = [ls.columns.values.tolist()]
values.extend(ls.values.tolist())

spread = client.open(SPREADSHEET)
spread.values_update(WORKSHEET, params={'valueInputOption': 'USER_ENTERED'}, body={'values': values})
```

### Pattern ２:

このパターンでは、[gspread-dataframe](https://github.com/robin900/gspread-dataframe)のライブラリを使用します。

#### From:

```py
ls = df.loc[0:0]
ls = ls.to_json()

spread = client.open(SPREADSHEET) 
sheet = spread.worksheet(WORKSHEET)
worksheet.append_row(ls)
```

#### To:

```py
ls = df.loc[0:0]

spread = client.open(SPREADSHEET) 
sheet = spread.worksheet(WORKSHEET)
gd.set_with_dataframe(sheet, ls)
```

この場合、`import gspread_dataframe as gd`を使用します。

#### References:

- [values_update(range, params=None, body=None)](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=values_update#gspread.models.Spreadsheet.values_update)
- [gspread-dataframe](https://github.com/robin900/gspread-dataframe)

Comment: set_with_dataframe 側でうまいことできました。
ありがとうございます！